# Products, Orders, and Customers Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to figure out what the appropriate ActiveRecord associations would be for my models. I want to create a very barebones ecommerce site. I want to have a system for upgrading and repairing products, so having access to a user's order history is important.

My current setup is as follows:

**User**

```
has_many :products, :through => :orders

has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Orders**

```
belongs_to :user

has_many :products
```

**Products**

```
belongs_to :orders
```

My first question is does this make sense? I'm concerned with the belongs_to :orders part of Products because I want to make sure a product can be part of many different orders (for obvious reasons). If this is wrong/right, what would be the neccessary migrations needed for the correct relationship?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have many to many relationship between the Product and the Order model. You can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association if you do not want to use the join table, otherwise there is only one option `has_many :through`

Comment: If I use HABTM then the semantics don't sound right but I see what you mean. It would seem like I'd want "belongs_to_many" which i suppose doesn't exist. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: No. There is no need of `belongs_to_many` as it would be similar to existing `has_many :through` and `HABTM`. `belongs_to` is used on the side of the association where we keep the `foreign key`. So, how can you handle `belongs_to_many`? There must be another join table to handle this, if this is the case then it can be done via existing `many to many` associations.

Answer (score 6):

I realize the post is quite old but since I was facing the same issue, it might be interesting to add some clarity for the followers. As @ManojMonga said in the comments, here you need to use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. So models will look like :

**User**

```
has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :products, through: :orders
```

**Order**

```
belongs_to :user
has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

**Product**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
```

Then, as explained in the [Active Record Association Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) , you will need to create a join table that will hold the orders and products foreign key. Migration looks like this :

```
class OrdersProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders_products, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to  :order, index: true
      t.belongs_to  :product, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then, after you've run the migration, you'll be able to use [has_and_belongs_to_many methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference).
Remember when you create your join table that in a has_an_belongs_to_many association, Active Record will look for a table named from the 2 tables name concatenated by alphabetical order. If you wish to name it otherwise, you will have to specify it in models as following :

**Order**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :join_table => "new_tables_name"
```

**Products**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :orders, :join_table => "new_tables_name"
```

Finally, `the has_many :products, through: :orders` in the User's model isn't mandatory. It will just allow to access products through users.
That's it, I'll be happy if it can be of any help. I'm using Rails 4.1 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Products `has_one :order`. This will allow you to use things like `@product.order`, but it won't actually create the foreign key for order in the products database table.

Comment: But that wording implies that for each product, there is one order. I want to make sure that a product can be part of many different orders from different users. I want to be able to use things like user.products and order.products but ensure that products aren't tied exclusively to one order or user. i.e. User A and User B both ordered Product A in different orders on different dates.